# Does the deleted question "Why is Git better than Subversion?" deserve a historical lock?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question

The question [Why is Git better than Subversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871/why-is-git-better-than-subversion) was one of the first thousand posts  on Stack Overflow.

It is obviously not constructive by current standards and has 37 answers. However, unlike most questions that get lots of answers, a large number of these are many-paragraph explanations, not just few-sentence remarks. The question had 53k views and a score of 395.

It's currently deleted. Does it deserve to be undeleted and historically locked?

Comment: Of course it does, for the reasons you listed.  It's hard to think of a better lock candidate than this.

Comment: Stunningly, it appears that all of the answers on page 1 are useful in some way. You have to make it all the way to page 2 to find an answer that you could reasonably describe as *bad*. I think this one is worth preserving for that reason alone.

Comment: More generally, though I find the *titular* question problematic (cf Gorilla vs Shark), I don't think that even today there would be anything wrong with a question regarding the advantages and disadvantages of Git as compared to Subversion. Not only is that a very interesting question, likely to be useful to many developers, but it encourages good, substantive answers and really isn't all that subjective.

Comment: One interesting fact is that it took well over a year for the top answer to be completed. Doesn't that indicate that new off-topic questions should also stay open at least a year, to see what happens? Or was life that different in the 00's?

Comment: **LOCKED** -- the system works.

Answer (score 19):

> **`POLL`** Vote up to support undeletion and locking, vote down to oppose.

Answer (score 2):

Git and svn are both moving targets. So a locked question is obsolete from birth and only gets more obsolete as time goes by.

Comment: Eh... The question was deleted once already.  It won't survive on its own without the lock.

Comment: I'm opposed to the original undeletion on the grounds of progressive uselessness over time. I know I won't win the argument.